# Suppose $\alpha$ is a finite ordinal. Prove $\alpha\in\omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, order-theory

I am reading the proof of this statement:
[image]

Below are theorems and statement mentioned in the proof:
[image: 3.4.6]
(i): Suppose $\beta$ is an infinite ordinal, then $\omega\leq \beta$ and $|\beta^\dagger| = |\beta|$

What I don't understand is why $\omega\subseteq n$ if $m\not\in \omega$. If $m\not\in\omega$, we have $\omega\subseteq m$ by 3.4.6. But $m\not\in n$, how is $\omega \in n$? And I have similar question for $n\subseteq m$. And I wonder why there is an injective function from $m^\dagger$ to $n$ especially we already have $n\subset m^\dagger$? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If $\omega\subseteq m$, let $x\in \omega\subseteq m$.  Since $m\in\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is transitive, $x\in \alpha$.  Since $x\in m$, it follows by minimality of $m$ that $x\not\in\alpha\setminus n$.  Therefore $x\in n$.  Hence every member of $\omega$ is a member of $n$ so $\omega\subseteq n$.
2. Since $m\in\alpha\setminus n$, $m\not\in n$.  By the trichotomy, $n\subseteq m$.
3. Since $m\in\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is transitive, $m\subseteq\alpha$, and both together imply that $m^\dagger = m\cup\{m\}\subseteq \alpha$.  We're assuming there is an injective function $h:\alpha\to n$, the the restriction of $h$ to $m^\dagger$ is an injective function of $m^\dagger$ to $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Could you explain more about the third point? Are $m\in\alpha$ and  $\{m\}\subset\alpha$ the same thing? And why do we assume such injective function exists? We are assuming $n\subset\alpha$. If there has to be an injective function, shouldn't it be $n\to \alpha$.

Comment: @user836844: Yes, $m\in\alpha$ and $\{m\}\subseteq\alpha$ are equivalent.  The exercise begins with $\alpha$ is equinumerous with $n\in\omega$, so there is a bijective function $\alpha\to n$ which is also injective.